# How can I add a button IF a value is not undefined inside the navigation params?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I currently have a function as such:

```
renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>Let's configure to begin...</Text>
    );
  }
```

I want to make it so there is a button underneath if the param is defined (i.e. if certain value exists) so I tried:

```
renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>Let's configure to begin...</Text>
      if(this.props.navigation.params.hasValue !== 'undefined'){
        <Button />
      }
    );
  }
```

However, I get `Unexpected token, expected "," (54:6)` am I missing something to be able to do a conditional rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective: Using JavaScript to render children in JSX. Checkout this documentation, directly from React.

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions-as-children

This demonstrates exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored

```
renderHeader = () => {
  return (
    <React.fragment>
      <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>Let's configure to begin...</Text>
      { this.props.navigation.params.hasValue !== undefined &&
        <Button/> }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: But I am working with React Native, I believe it would be different?

Comment: I've added a code snippet to my answer, please try this.

Comment: Also, when comparing to 'undefined' in you original question, I'm assuming you're trying to check if the value of  [this.props.navigation.params.hasValue] is undefined. Which you would want to use 'undefined' with not singly/doubly quotes which would make it of type string, when undefined is of type undefined

Comment: You were right about <Fragment> it's just "Fragment" as opposed to React.Fragment

Comment: React.Fragment and Fragment is the same element. When using dot notation you're accessing it directly on the React default import. I'm assuming in your file you're doing something like: ___________________   `import React, { Fragment } from 'react'` at the top of your file. Theres also a **shorthand** syntax https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax

Answer (score 0):

You are not using jsx correctly, which is why you are getting the error complaining about the unexpected token. The common way to conditionally insert an element would be the following:

```
renderHeader = () => {
  return (
    <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>Let's configure to begin...</Text>
    {this.props.navigation.params.hasValue !== 'undefined' &&
      <Button />
    }
  );
}
```

or more generically stated:

```
{ someCondition &&
  <ElementToInsertIfSomeCondition />
}
```

Because compound conditions short circuit, if `someCondition` is false, the condition returns false and there is no element, otherwise the evaluation of the condition moves on to the right side and returns your element.

Comment: Mm I tried doing it as you mention and I get the same error, I am working with React Native any chance that's different?